# JavaScript hasClass ignoring element's class?

Tags: javascript, jquery, filter, jquery-isotope, slidedown

I have an [Isotope](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/index.html) filter menu and I'm using hash history so the filters are still set if a user comes back to the page. Because we are using .slideDown to expand sub-menu items, the sub-menu items are hidden when you come back to the page even though some filters within them are selected.

I'm trying to use:

```
if ($('#option1').hasClass('.selected')) {
    $('.level-two').slideDown('fast');
}
```

However, since the class "selected" is being generated by the jQuery filter (Isotope), it's being ignored.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/RevConcept/swT84/

HTML:

```
<nav>           

            <div id="options" class="combo-filters">

                <div class="option-combo location">

                    <ul class="filter option-set group level-one" data-filter-group="location"> 

                        <li class="hidden"><a href="#filter-location-any" data-filter-value="" class="selected">any</a></li>

                        <li><a id="option1" href="#filter-location-exterior" data-filter-value=".exterior" class="trigger-two">exterior</a></li>

                        <li><a id="option2" href="#filter-location-interior" data-filter-value=".interior" class="trigger-two">interior</a></li>

                    </ul>

                </div>

                <div class="option-combo illumination">

                    <ul class="filter option-set group level-two" data-filter-group="illumination"> 

                        <li class="hidden"><a href="#filter-illumination-any" data-filter-value="" class="selected">any</a></li>

                        <li><a href="#filter-illumination-illuminated" data-filter-value=".illuminated" class="trigger-three">illuminated</a></li>

                        <li><a href="#filter-illumination-non-illuminated" data-filter-value=".non-illuminated" class="trigger-three">non-illuminated</a></li>

                    </ul>

                </div>

                <div class="option-combo mount">

                    <ul class="filter option-set group level-three" data-filter-group="mount"> 

                        <li class="hidden"><a href="#filter-mount-any" data-filter-value="" class="selected">any</a></li>

                        <li><a href="#filter-mount-wall" data-filter-value=".wall">wall</a></li>

                        <li><a href="#filter-mount-ground" data-filter-value=".ground">ground</a></li>

                    </ul>

                </div>


            </div><!--end options-->

        </nav>
```

CSS:

```
header nav ul.level-two, header nav ul.level-three {
display:none;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
$(function(){
    $('.level-one').hide().fadeIn('fast');
});


$(".trigger-two").one('click', function(){
    $(".level-two").slideDown('fast'); 
});


$(".trigger-three").one('click', function(){
    $(".level-three").slideDown('fast'); 
});


if ($('#option1').is('selected')) {
    $('.level-two').slideDown('fast');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than copy the same process of each click with a repeated function you could always programatically trigger the clicks on the .selected anchors.

```
$('.option-combo a.selected').trigger('click');
```

A fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jgkwd/

Comment: This works beautifully on the fiddle...but for some reason when I go back to the page on my dev site the sub-menu options are hidden again: [example](http://revelationconcept.com/hosting/trademark_temp/)

Comment: I may be wrong but it may be because of the order you have the javascript files included in your page. The script that add the .selected class is added after the the toggle script so the `$(document).ready(function())` and `$(function())` (which are the same as far as I know) are being queued and then called in the wrong order.

Comment: I had tried that and it didn't help, but I think I had a combination of other issues at that point...you were right! Thanks a million ;)

Answer (score 2):

I guess  you are missing a '.'

```
if ($('#option1').is('.selected')) {
    $('.level-two').slideDown('fast');
}
```

Comment: Yes, I was thanks...but adding it doesn't resolve the problem. If I create my own class on the element and use that then it works...it's only having a problem with the dynamic "selected" class.

Comment: How are you setting the class. Is it using addClass()

Comment: I'm not doing it directly, it's built into the Isotope options...but yes, it appears they are using addClass/removeClass etc. If you go to my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RevConcept/swT84/2/) you will see "ISOTOPE SETTINGS" towards the bottom of the javascript area.